# clearInterval() is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to start the interval on mouseenter event and i have to stop it on mouseleave.

'clearInterval' is not stopping the interval when 'setInterval' is started by 'mouseenter ' event while it is working properly when 'setInterval' is started by 'mousedown' event

demo.ts

```
  interval_bs:any;
  startInterval(){    
    this.interval_bs=setInterval(()=>{
      if(this.activeIndex<3){
        this.activeIndex+=1;
      }
      else{
        this.activeIndex=0;
      }     
    },2000)   
  }  

  stopInterval(){   
    clearInterval(this.interval_bs);   
  }
```

demo.html

```
<div (mouseenter)="startInterval()" (mouseleave)="stopInterval()"  >     
      <ng-template ngFor let-bs [ngForOf]="back_screens" let-bsi="index" >
        <img [src]="bs.image" *ngIf="activeIndex==bsi" >
      </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: put a console.log inside the `stopInterval()` maybe the function isn't being called at all

Comment: checked it. it is being called

Comment: If you add `console.log(this)` to both methods, what does it print?

Comment: Same message is printed In both methods : 

HomeComponent {
activeIndex:0
interval_bs:ZoneTask
isSecondScreen:true
__proto__:Object

Comment: understood the problem. the problem is that startInterval() method is running multiple time when i move the mouse pointer on same div in which i have applied mouseenter event.
Is there any way to call startInterval() method only once when mouse pointer be in that particular div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now problem has been solved. Declare a variable 'start_count' and initialise it to zero. 
on '(mouseleave)' event, reset 'start_count' to zero.
Now on '(mouseenter)' event increase the 'start_count' and apply a condition to 'setInterval()' method

```
interval_bs:any;  
start_count:number=0;
startInterval(){   
    this.start_count+=1;
    if(this.start_count==1){
      this.interval_bs=setInterval(()=>{
        if(this.activeIndex<3){
          this.activeIndex+=1;
        }
        else{
          this.activeIndex=0;
        }        
      },2000)     
    }

  }  

  stopInterval(){   
    this.start_count=0;
    clearInterval(this.interval_bs);   
  }
```

Comment: :) @PardeepJain